# Android Studio 2.2: Gradle: Fixplugin version and sync project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[Gradle problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKQBP.png) 
I"m update build.gradle:
`}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

`and`
gradle-wrapper.propertie:`

### `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip`

app\build.gradel:
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'`

### }

**Location** `C:/Software/gardle2.14/gradle-2.14`

**I"m get this note:**
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to `"f45c7e54f5c7108ea208060be3303c44dd2ae899"`

Thanks for support